# multiple dynamically created buttons, on click use the same function but take dynamically sourced paramaters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically create a table, in each row of the table I want there to be a button that will geolocate the address on that line only. the code below works if there is only one row returned, if there are multiple rows it doesn't

I would really appreciate some help as this is driving me nuts, thanking you all in advance!

```
 data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "php/censusdata3.php",
          data: data
        }).success(function(data)
            {
                  var tr, td;
                  var str;
                    $.each(data,function(index,point)
                    {
                      tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
                      str=point.Readable;
                      tr = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
                      td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                      //td.setAttribute("align", "center");
                      td.innerHTML = point.Forename;
                      td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                      td.innerHTML = point.Surname;
                      td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                      td.innerHTML = point.Age;
                      td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                      td.innerHTML = '<input id="location-address" type="text" class="form-control" value="'+str+'" required/><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="map-address-btn"><span>Find Location</span></button>';
                      $(document).ready(function() {

                          // get map button functionality
                          $("#map-address-btn").click(function(event){
                            event.preventDefault();     
                            var address = $("#location-address").val(); // grab the address from the input field
                            codeAddress(address); // geocode the address
                          });
                        });

                    });

      });
```

updated code:

```
}).success(function(data)
    {
          var tr, td;
          var str;
            $.each(data,function(index,point)
            {
              tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
              str=point.Readable;
              tr = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
              td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
              //td.setAttribute("align", "center");
              td.innerHTML = point.Forename;
              td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
              td.innerHTML = point.Surname;
              td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);// I think the i 's are what is breakingit!!
              td.innerHTML = point.Age;
              td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
              td.innerHTML = '<input class="address" type="text" class="form-control" value="'+str+'" required/><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="map-address-btn"><span>Find Location</span></button>';
              $(document).ready(function() {

                $("table tbody").on("click", "button", function () {  //listen for <button> clicks on your table
                  var btn = $(this);  //reference to the clicked button
                  var tableRow = btn.closest("tr");   //find the table row the button is in.
                  var address = tableRow.find("input.address").val();  //find the input field in that row that you want
                  console.log(address );  display the value  
                  });

                  // // get map button functionality
                  // $("#map-address-btn").click(function(event){
                  //   event.preventDefault();     
                  //   var address = $("#location-address").val();         // grab the address from the input field
                  //   codeAddress(address);                   // geocode the address
                  // });
                });
```

});

The latest iteration with the changes made:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function(){
      $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
          "action": "test"
        };
        data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "php/censusdata3.php",
          data: data
        }).success(function(data)
            {
                  var tr, td;
                  var str;
                    $.each(data,function(index,point)
                    {
                      tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
                      str=point.Readable;
                      tr = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
                      td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                      //td.setAttribute("align", "center");
                      td.innerHTML = point.Forename;
                      td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                      td.innerHTML = point.Surname;
                      td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                      td.innerHTML = point.Age;
                      td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                      td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control location-address" value="'+str+'" required/><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm map-address-btn"><span>Find Location</span></button>';


                    });

      });
        return false;         
                    });

      });
    });
    </script>
```

and this lad is down in the bottom of a script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      // get map button functionality
      $(".map-address-btn").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();     
        var address = $(this).parent().find('.map-address-btn').val(); // grab the address from the input field
        codeAddress(address); // geocode the address
      });
    });
```

Now the table won't populate at all, again thanks for all of your help.

Comment: It's because of the id change your jquery click handler to a class instead of an id

Comment: I've added a working fiddle. it should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i said in the comment, it's because of your Ids, they must be unique. Use class instead:

```
data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "php/censusdata3.php",
          data: data
        }).success(function(data)
            {
                  var tr, td;
                  var str;
                    $.each(data,function(index,point)
                    {
                      tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
                      str=point.Readable;
                      tr = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
                      td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                      //td.setAttribute("align", "center");
                      td.innerHTML = point.Forename;
                      td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                      td.innerHTML = point.Surname;
                      td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                      td.innerHTML = point.Age;
                      td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                      td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control location-address" value="'+str+'" required/><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm map-address-btn"><span>Find Location</span></button>';
                    });



            });

            $('#tbody').off("click",".map-adress-btn");
            // get map button functionality
            $('#tbody').on("click",".map-address-btn", function(event){
              var address = $(this).parent().find('.location-address').val(); // grab the address from the input field
              codeAddress(address); // geocode the address
            });
```

working fiddle:

[http://jsfiddle.net/Leqkqkx0/1](http://jsfiddle.net/Leqkqkx0/1/)

Comment: And you just added tons of click handlers.

Comment: indeed  I've just changed his code so that it is working, but you are right. Creating the click on a "on" is a lot better. And the document ready is weirdly placed.

Comment: No your code is going to end up calling `codeAddress` tons of times on a single click. Every loop that adds a row, it adds a another click handler. You are not adding it to the current row, you are adding it to every row on every iteration. You need to move it out of the each.

Comment: I would like to learn how to do it properly, is there anything else you can tell me?

Comment: Well another problem is that each time you will call your "ajax call", you will double your event handler. You could remove it before but I'm not sure it's a good practice

Comment: skatanick you are only brilliant, that worked perfectly $('#tbody').off..... was brilliant, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ids need to be singular so use a class.

```
<input class="address" ... />
```

Now instead multiple clicks and adding multiple handlers, just add one to the table body and use event delegation.

```
$("table tbody").off("click.geocode".on("click.geocode", "button", function () {  //listen for <button> clicks on your table
    var btn = $(this);  //reference to the clicked button
    var tableRow = btn.closest("tr");   //find the table row the button is in.
    var address = tableRow.find("input.address").val();  //find the input field in that row that you want
    console.log(address );  display the value
    codeAddress(address); // geocode the address
});
```

This code does not have to be in the success method of the Ajax call, it can be attached document.ready or onload or at the bottom of the page after the table.

Comment: OK so I have tried that but I think I might have missed something

Comment: As I said in my code, do not add it in the each/success method and there is no need for document ready after the page has loaded. Put the code outside of the Ajax call.

Comment: So where do I put the button functionality? in the body? Sorry this must seem very remedial to you all.

Comment: Put it after the Ajax call...   .success(function(){...}); /*put code here */